# Rails, Paperclip; Validate Attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, paperclip-validation

I want validate the file content of a paperclip attachment (https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip).

My model:

```
class PackageArchive < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :package
  has_attached_file :package

  validates_attachment :package,
            :presence => true
  validate :open

  def open
    Rails.logger.debug "####" + original_filename.inspect
    file_content = `cat "#{package.path}"`
  end
end
```

"cat" abort with error message "No such file or directory". It there a way to get the correct file name?

Comment: I believe validate happens before saving, therefore there is no file on the disk either.

Comment: What are the values of `package.path` and `original_filename`? If the file does exist, it may be that you are looking for it in the wrong directory.